# I got System.FormatException from trying replacing a part of string with value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a javascript file and it contains below js script

```
(function() {
    try {
        var click = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window});
        var field = document.querySelector('input[type="email"]');
        setTimeout(function() {
            field.dispatchEvent(click);
            field.focus();
            field.value="{0}";
        }, 500);
        return true;
    } catch(err) {
        return false; 
    }
})();
```

And I read that as string using below code:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\\Resources\\script\\myjavascript.js";
var raw = File.ReadAllText(path);
var args = new object[] { "my_username" };
Console.WriteLine(raw, args);
```

I got error: **Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll**

As I try to replace **{0}** with **"my_username"**.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer based on PepitoSh approach is below:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\\Resources\\script\\myjavascript.js";
var raw = File.ReadAllText(path);
var script = raw.Replace("{0}", "my_username");
Console.WriteLine(script);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since indeed you have to escape the curly braces that are not part of the formatting, I'd recommend another approach in this specific case:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\\Resources\\script\\myjavascript.js";
var raw = File.ReadAllText(path);
raw = raw.Replace("{0}", "my_username");
Console.WriteLine(raw);
```

Comment: Yes... I prefer your approach as I don't wanna make changes in js file. So I use REPLACE instead of FORMAT. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape all other `{` and `}` and leave only `"{0}"` for the `string.format` to work.

Also I would add a js object with properties for all variables and use that as an argument or a global object in js scripts, so I only have to replace the values once for multiple scripts.